# htaccess redirect from one url to another url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am bit stuck one redirecting one url to another url.

I want to redirect

```
http://samedomain.com/?abc
```

to

```
http://samedomain.com/news/title
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Redirect 301 http://samedomain.com/?abc http://samedomain.com/news/title

Comment: Sorry I tried with it but didn't work. I think ? is causing the problem

Comment: Do you already have some rewrite rules?

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite rule will redirect http://samedomain.com/?abc to http://samedomain.com/news/title:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^abc$
RewriteRule ^ /news/title/? [L,R=301]
```